# Design for efficient querying

Tags: database-design, architecture, nosql

I have a NoSQL database with a `User` collection and `Post` collection. Each `User` has one `Post` and can follow other `Users` (friends with them).

A `User` can only view a `Post` from a friend that he has not viewed before. Once it's viewed, it is no longer displayed to him.

I am trying to figure out a way to design this requirement such that it is efficient in retrieving `Posts` that a `User` has not viewed.

I have two ideas, neither which seem very efficient:

1. Create a subcollection under `User` called `NonViewedPosts` where each time a friend posts, their friend's post id is added under that subcollection. When that user views the post, it's entry is removed. But that means whenever a user posts they have to add themselves to all their friends `NotViewedPosts` subcollections. If they have a lot of friends, this can be inefficient
2. Have a subcollection under `Post` called `Viewed` that begins empty and as the post gets viewed, it fills up. Then I'd have to query `Viewed` to see if I find myself in that collection for every friends post. If I have a lot of friends, and if my friends have a lot of views, then this is also inefficient

Are there other solutions that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Or how about adding a new column in the schema that you modify after the user views the post? When you read, you could write a query that filters out the results based on this column

Comment: @RamkumarVenkataraman I'm working with documents and collections over tables with columns, so I think this idea would be kind of like the second I mentioned in my post. I don't think I could add a single property (column) under Post to handle every friend's view state. Maybe I'm not understanding

Answer (score 2):

When building systems like this, you should almost always try to optimize for the read case, and not the write case.  In this scenario, your read is still going to be a write, but you still want to optimize for the case where the user is "reading" i.e. looking for new posts to read.  Correct?  Likely the read scenario will be far more common than the posting case.

Therefore, would then optimize toward the push model (scenario 1).  There is no scenario where you don't either have to optimize for one or the other.  You will have to either push or pull the information about friends posts.

Comment: Exactly, the "read" will be a lot more frequent than the "write". I was just wondering if there was something I hadn't thought of to make the read query simpler. Does scenario 1 sound like a bad design? Say a popular user (famous person) has 100,000 followers, then they would have to write to 100,000 different User's "NonViewedPosts" subcollections?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I'm not sure if the read would be all that more frequent. A read for this scenario would really only need to happen in the launch of my application (getting all unviewed posts). After the launch, there would be no more huge reads only just document listeners for new posts, from that point it's however frequent a User posts (writes) until relaunching the application.

Comment: You are likely thinking about reads that result in content to view.  The user will likely read many times looking for new content to view.  Most of those will come up empty, but they will still incur the cost of a read.